# how to read environment variable or property in logback.xml and print that property in every log line

Tags: java, logging, logback, jvm-arguments, java-opts

I would like to read environment variable or property in every log line from logback.xml. 
**Example** 
if I hit **echo "${FOO_INFO}"** the result is "FOO_RESULT", this FOO_RESULT I need to print it in the every log line.

After adding JAVA_OPTS="-Dfoo.info=${FOO_INFO}"

I tried below option:-

**Option :** added  and calling %d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} ${FOO_INFO}- %msg%n

Answer (score 0):

The documentation indicates you can include a system property by using a [PatternLayout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) with the [property conversion pattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#property) `%property{key}` where `key` is the system property name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system properties like `${SOME_VAR}` and pass that value into your application with `-D` while running.

So in my case:

```xml
    <logger name="com.example.app" level="${SOME_LOGGING_LEVEL}"/>
```

And:

```java
java -DSOME_LOGGING_LEVEL=WARN MyApp
```

Verified and it works. And ofc it works in docker, docker-compose and Kubernetes as this is Logback feature. See [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#definingProps)